# I want that on the submitting a form, a message should display and should fade out after 5 seconds

Tags: jquery, html

I want that on submitting the form successfully a message should be displayed and should fade out after 5 seconds.

My code on which i worked out is not working

```
<html>
  <head> 
    <title>Untitled Document</title> 
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-           `enter code here`latest.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   </head> 
   <body> 
    <form method='post'>
      <input type='text' name='txt'></input>
        <button type='submit' id='but1'>CLICK ME</button>
          <div id=deletesuccess > hiiiiiiiiiii </div> 
            </form>
             <script type="text/javascript"> 

              $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
              $('#deletesuccess').delay(1000).fadeOut();
               });
              </script>

      </body> 
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    $('#deletesuccess').fadeIn();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#deletesuccess').fadeOut();
    }, 5000);
   return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to prevent the native form submit for five seconds, then trigger it

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var self = this;

    $('#deletesuccess').delay(1000).fadeOut(4000, function() {

         self.submit();

    });
});
```

Comment: this is doing somethig else,

it is first taking 5 seconds and fading the div and then submitting the form.

I want to submit the form first then fadeout the div after five secs.

Comment: @ShivaSaxena - and how do you submit a form, which reloads the page, and then fade something out on a page that you've left ?